# PHP file only returns one (latest) JSON object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, response

While performing a GET request to my server, the .PHP file I have set-up only returns the latest JSON object, not the entire array.  I think it is getting overwritten the array, not adding to it but I'm not too strong with PHP and could be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks for any help in advance, code is below.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE uni_year = '$uni_year' AND uni_course = '$uni_course'") or die(mysql_error());

if(!empty($result)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
       // $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

       // while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        // temp array
        $books = array();
        $books["list_id"] = $result["list_id"];
        $books["book_title"] = $result["book_title"];
        $books["uni_course"] = $result["uni_course"];
        $books["uni_year"] = $result["uni_year"];
        $books["book_author"] = $result["book_author"];
        $books["book_price"] = $result["book_price"];
        $books["book_year"] = $result["book_year"];
        $books["isbn"] = $result["isbn"];
    //}
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // user node
        $response["books"] = array();

        array_push($response["books"], $books);

    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "num of rows bigger than zero";
    }
} else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        echo json_encode($response);
}


    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: You need a while loop for your `result = mysql_fetch_array($result);`.... like the one that's commented out in your code..... except the loop has to go as far as `array_push($response["books"], $books);`

Comment: And you don't need all those individual column assignments to $books.... select only the columns you need from the database, and fetch as an associative array, and just push the $result  (row) to $response['books']

Comment: And then move into the 21st century, and switch to MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements and bind variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only fetching the first record from the result (`$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);`).

You need to fetch them in a loop:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE uni_year = '$uni_year' AND uni_course = '$uni_course'") or die(mysql_error());

if(!empty($result)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $books = array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $book = array();
            $book["list_id"] = $row["list_id"];
            $book["book_title"] = $row["book_title"];
            $book["uni_course"] = $row["uni_course"];
            $book["uni_year"] = $row["uni_year"];
            $book["book_author"] = $row["book_author"];
            $book["book_price"] = $row["book_price"];
            $book["book_year"] = $row["book_year"];
            $book["isbn"] = $row["isbn"];
            $books[] = $book;
        }
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // user node
        $response["books"] = $books;
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "num of rows bigger than zero";
    }
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No product found";
}


echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: I'll note that there are a large number of things here that could be done better, but this is the closest to the intention of the original code.